# Disable Format for some messages

Tags: python, logging, sh

I am working with pythons logging library developing a data analysis pipeline. I am logging both custom messages about what steps are being run and also the raw output of invoked programs. I am using `sh.py` to simplify the calling of shell commands. It lets me define a callback function to process each line of `STDOUT/STDERR`.

I would like to be able to define my call back function to log each line to the log file with out the formatting (these programs output a lot of lines):

```
log.info("Starting %s run on %s", program_name, file_name)

def call_back(line):
    log.info.NOFORMAT(line)  # do the no format logging

sh.program(args, _out=call_back)

log.info("Finished running %s", program_name)
```

My resulting log file would then look like:

```
"""<br>
2016-01-22|{INFO}: Starting $SOME_PROGRAM$ on $SOME_FILE$<br>
program_output_line<br>
program_output_line<br>
program_output_line<br>
program_output_line<br>
program_output_line<br>
2016-01-22|{INFO}: Finished running $SOME_PROGRAM$<br>
"""
```

Does anyone know how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look into logging.config https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.config.html

Basically, you would define a dedicated logger that writes to the same file as your root logger but uses a stripped down formatter, like `format=%(message)s`. In call_back you would then fetch that logger explicitly: `logging.getlogger(logger_name)`.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this by extending the `logging.Formatter` class. If a log message ships with an optional metadata `simple=True` - **then no formatting will be rendered for that specific message**.

```
class ConditionalFormatter(logging.Formatter):
    def format(self, record):
        if hasattr(record, 'simple') and record.simple:
            return record.getMessage()
        else:
            return logging.Formatter.format(self, record)


rotating_file_formatter = ConditionalFormatter('%(asctime)s %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
rotating_file.setFormatter(rotating_file_formatter)
# ...
```

- **With formatting**

  ```
  logging.info("starting application ...")
  ```

  log output:

  ```
  2020-05-01 19:38:05,337 INFO - starting application ...
  ```
- **Without formatting**

  ```
  logging.info("starting application ...", extra={'simple': True})
  ```

  log output:

  ```
  starting application ...
  ```

---

## Full Example

In this script I'm using console logging and file logging. Among general logs, I'm invoking a command `ls -ahl /` and piping all of it's output straight to log without formatting:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import logging
import subprocess
import sys
from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler


def initialize_logger(log_file_path):
    rotating_file = RotatingFileHandler(log_file_path, mode='a', maxBytes=5 * 1024 * 1024, backupCount=5, encoding=None, delay=0)

    class ConditionalFormatter(logging.Formatter):
        def format(self, record):
            if hasattr(record, 'simple') and record.simple:
                return record.getMessage()
            else:
                return logging.Formatter.format(self, record)

    rotating_file_formatter = ConditionalFormatter('%(asctime)s %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
    rotating_file.setFormatter(rotating_file_formatter)
    rotating_file.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    console_logger = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
    console_logger_formatter = logging.Formatter('%(message)s')
    console_logger.setFormatter(console_logger_formatter)
    console_logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

    root_logger = logging.getLogger()
    root_logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    root_logger.addHandler(rotating_file)
    root_logger.addHandler(console_logger)


def main():
    initialize_logger('/var/log/my-app.log')
    logging.info('starting application ...')

    command = ["ls", "-ahl"]
    working_directory = '/'
    logging.info(f'running {command} ...')
    process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, cwd=working_directory)

    with process.stdout:
        for line in iter(process.stdout.readline, b''):
            line = line.decode('utf-8')
            line = line.strip()
            logging.debug(line, extra={'simple': True})

    exit_code = process.wait()
    if exit_code == 0:
        logging.debug(f'command "{command}" finished successfully')
    else:
        logging.debug(f'command "{command}" failed with exit code {exit_code}')

    logging.info('stopping application')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

stdout:

```
starting application ...
running ['ls', '-ahl'] ...
stopping application
```

output file `/var/log/my-app.log`:

```
2020-05-01 19:48:06,347 INFO - starting application ...
2020-05-01 19:48:06,347 INFO - running ['ls', '-ahl', '/'] ...
total 112K
drwxr-xr-x  25 root root 4.0K Apr 30 06:55 .
drwxr-xr-x  25 root root 4.0K Apr 30 06:55 ..
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4.0K Mar 31 06:39 bin
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root 4.0K May  1 06:02 boot
drwxrwxr-x   2 root root 4.0K Oct 11  2018 cdrom
drwxr-xr-x  20 root root 4.2K Apr 30 06:54 dev
drwxr-xr-x 154 root root  12K Apr 30 06:54 etc
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root 4.0K Oct 11  2018 home
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root   33 Apr 30 06:55 initrd.img -> boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-99-generic
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root   33 Apr 30 06:55 initrd.img.old -> boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-96-generic
drwxr-xr-x  21 root root 4.0K Oct 20  2018 lib
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4.0K Oct 20  2018 lib32
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4.0K Jul 25  2018 lib64
drwx------   2 root root  16K Oct 11  2018 lost+found
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root 4.0K Oct 15  2018 media
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root 4.0K Jun 20  2019 mnt
drwxrwxrwx  23 root root 4.0K May  1 16:56 opt
dr-xr-xr-x 302 root root    0 Apr 23 19:57 proc
drwx------   6 root root 4.0K Apr 29 22:31 root
drwxr-xr-x  40 root root 1.4K May  1 14:44 run
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  12K Feb  9 12:00 sbin
drwxr-xr-x  15 root root 4.0K Apr 25 11:15 snap
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4.0K Jul 25  2018 srv
dr-xr-xr-x  13 root root    0 May  1 18:53 sys
drwxrwxrwt  32 root root 4.0K May  1 19:39 tmp
drwxr-xr-x  11 root root 4.0K Oct 20  2018 usr
drwxr-xr-x  15 root root 4.0K Jun 20  2019 var
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root   30 Apr 30 06:55 vmlinuz -> boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-99-generic
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root   30 Apr 30 06:55 vmlinuz.old -> boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-96-generic
2020-05-01 19:48:06,357 DEBUG - command "['ls', '-ahl', '/']" finished successfully
2020-05-01 19:48:06,357 INFO - stopping application
```

Answer (score 3):

You can setup a `logging.Formatter` object for the handler that will be used by the `Logger`. It should implement the `format(record)` method that will return the string that will be actually displayed.

```
import sh
import logging

class MyFormatter(logging.Formatter):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        logging.Formatter.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self._enableFormatFlag = True

    def enableFormat(self):
        self._enableFormatFlag = True
    def disableFormat(self):
        self._enableFormatFlag = False

    def format(self, record):
        if self._enableFormatFlag:
            return logging.Formatter.format(self, record)
        else:
            return record.getMessage()

logger = logging.getLogger('myapp')
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
handler = logging.StreamHandler()
logger.addHandler(handler)
formatter = MyFormatter(fmt="prefix[%(message)s]suffix")
handler.setFormatter(formatter)


def callback(line):
    logger.info(line.strip())

logger.info("Will start program")
formatter.disableFormat()
sh.ls(['-l'],_out=callback)
formatter.enableFormat()
logger.info("Finished program")
```

PS: My previous answer was about getting the callback, sorry.