# How to configure custom logging formatter for pytest?

Tags: python, logging, pytest

I'm currently working in a python project using pytest and I use a logger to generate some logs in our tests. The thing my logger has a specific formatter class similar to [this other example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34954373/disable-format-for-some-messages) so I can trigger different formats for messages according to the situation.

My question would be: how can I configure pytest to use also my custom formatter when `log_cli=true`?

If I erase the `log_format` attribute from the pytest.ini, it simply generates the logs in a specific format (I guess hardcoded by pytest code) instead of taking the format of my logger.

Does anyone have any idea how to force / configure pytest logging to also use my custom formatter?